# How to implement printer picker using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have Used `UIPrinterPickerController` class to implement printer picker. Now I want to implement printer picker using **SwiftUI**. I tried my best but did not find any solution. I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is not so trivial, so here is possible approach. Tested & works with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Note: make sure you activate *Printing* in project *Signing & Capabilities* settings.

I don't have AirPrint printers around, so ... just searching

[image]

Demo code:

```
struct DemoPrinterPicker: View {
    @State private var showPicker = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Select Printer") {
            self.showPicker.toggle()
        }
        .background(PrinterPickerController(showPrinterPicker: $showPicker))
    }
}
```

SwiftUI representable (just shows printers picker, what to do with selected printer is your responsibility)

```
struct PrinterPickerController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var showPrinterPicker: Bool

    fileprivate let controller = UIViewController()

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        if showPrinterPicker && context.coordinator.activePicker == nil {
            let picker = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
            context.coordinator.activePicker = picker

            picker.delegate = context.coordinator
            picker.present(animated: true) { (picker, flag, error) in
                if let printer =  picker.selectedPrinter {
                    // << do anything needed with printer
                }

                context.coordinator.activePicker = nil
                self.showPrinterPicker = false
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPrinterPickerControllerDelegate {
        let owner: PrinterPickerController
        var activePicker: UIPrinterPickerController?

        init(_ owner: PrinterPickerController) {
            self.owner = owner
        }

        func printerPickerControllerParentViewController(_ printerPickerController: UIPrinterPickerController) -> UIViewController? {
            self.owner.controller
        }
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
}
```

Comment: Works great on mobile, but doesn't work on iPad as a rect & view source is needed for the controller to appear from.